# How to analyze .wav and .dat file?

Tags: wav

I want to read .wav or .dat files and plot the spectrum, for the plot spectrum I need the center frequency and bits per samples, in the .dat file I can find the center frequency but I can not find it in .wav
How can I calculate it?
[image: center freq in .dat file]

I can also find bits per samples in the .wav file  according to the canonical wave file format but not in the .dat file, is .dat file contain it?
[image: bits per sample in .wav file]

Is .dat file data stored in **little endian** like a .wav file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to find center frequency  in .wav file and bits per samples in .dat file

Comment: Please add all clarification, and your attempts, to the question by editing it

Comment: 1. WAV files don't contain information about frequencies, they are just a list of samples in a known rate and depth. 2. What is a DAT file? I don't think its a known file type, like WAV, but rather some generic name that your app is using.

Comment: @TDG  yes WAV files don't contain frequencies but when convert .wav to .dat file the center frequency will appear

Comment: OK, so that leaves us with my second question - what is dat file? How do you generate it from the wav file?